# `buildah unshare`: ERRO exec: "buildah-script.sh": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: buildah

The very command `buildah unshare buildah-script.sh` is in `man buildah`, but when I run it I'm getting,

```
❯ buildah unshare buildah-script.sh
ERRO exec: "buildah-script.sh": executable file not found in $PATH 
ERRO (unable to determine exit status)            
ERRO exit status 1
```

This is with,

```
buildah version 1.19.6 (image-spec 1.0.1-dev, runtime-spec 1.0.2-dev)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get around this by prefixing the script with `./`

```
buildah unshare ./buildah-script.sh
```